# How do I create alarm on SQS first requeue and not when it's deadlettered after, say, 10 requeues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I can create an alarm for messages entering a dead letter queue after the max requeue attempts is reached. However, I want to  set up an alarm to let me know when the source queue attempts it's first requeue.

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to be notified when a received message exceeds its invisibility time and becomes visible on the queue again? I don't think that information is available. There is a `ReceiveCount`, but I couldn't see how to get this value via the SQS API.